# Moving Ubuntu guest from Vista 32 to Windows 7 64 issue

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-vista, virtualbox, migration

As the title suggests, I ran into a problem when trying to migrate Ubuntu 12-04 guest from Vista32 Ultimate host to Win7-64 Ultimate host. I transferred the whole virtual machine and tried both adding it to VBox, and creating new form existing .vdi.

When staarting the machine, GRUB loader shows up, making me choose to boot from recovery mode, or perform memory tests, and then when proceeding to boot, I get this:

> Kernel panic - not syncing Attempted to kill init! exit code 0x0000004
>   ...
>     Spurious ack on isa0060 serio0. Some program might be trying to access hardware directly

**Original host details:**
AMD Athlon 64 X2 DualCore TK-55 1.80GHz
RAM 2GB DDR2
VirtualBox 4.2.4 r81684
Vista 32bit Ultimate SP2

**New host details:**
AMD FX-4100 QuadCore
RAM 8GB DDR3
VirtualBox 4.2.18 r88780
Windows 7 64 Ultimate SP1

Any suggestions...?

Comment: Do you have access to the original host?

Comment: This likely has to do with virtualization features of the new host rather the move from a 32-bit host to a 64-bit host.  Furthermore your previous CPU supported 64-bit operating systems.  What features does your new CPU have that your old CPU didn't have.  I assume you created a new virtual machine that matches the exact configuration of the old one and then attached the virtual hdd to it and it failed?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, I have the access.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, yes, I also think this has something to do with HW itself, but I can't tell what exactly. I think I read somewhere that some BIOS settings may affect the migration. I'm pretty sure I set up the exact same machine settings while creating it... what CPU features are we talking about?

Comment: @Less - I specifically call out virtualization features in my first comment

Comment: Oh... yes, sorry :) Well, this processor should support VT, if I'm not wrong (http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-4100.html). I might as well check the BIOS settings then..